# Return rows where a field has a specified count

Tags: sql, count

I have a table (DF)

```
+----+------+-----+
| ID |  PT  | AVG |
+----+------+-----+
| A  | 1.00 | 2.5 |
| A  | 2.00 | 3.5 |
| B  | 1.00 | 2.8 |
| B  | 2.00 | 2.6 |
| B  | 3.00 | 3.9 |
+----+------+-----+
```

I am trying to write a simple SQL statement to pull the ID that has 3 points.

I tried these 2 statements but I am doing it wrong

```
1. Returns all rows again

SELECT * FROM DF
WHERE PT BETWEEN '1.000' AND '3.000' 

2. Returns counts of rows

SELECT * FROM DF b    
WHERE b.PT=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.PT) FROM DF A WHERE A.ID=B.ID)
```

My desired output is:

```
+----+------+-----+
| ID |  PT  | AVG |
+----+------+-----+
| B  | 1.00 | 2.8 |
| B  | 2.00 | 2.6 |
| B  | 3.00 | 3.9 |
+----+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to find out which groups have a count of three rows. You can do that by using a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

The `HAVING` clause is used for conditions regarding aggregation, do not use the `WHERE` clause for this. Once you have those values, you can go back and select all rows from your table where the id column is `IN` the result set above:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE id IN(
   SELECT id
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY id
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 3);
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/339aa/2) example using your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM YourTable
             GROUP BY ID
             HAVING COUNT(*) = 3);
```